# Typescript remove values from array if it doesn't exist in multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a single dimensional and an array of Objects

```
array1 = [1, 3, 15, 16, 18];

array2 = [
       { id: 1, dinner : pizza },
       { id: 15, dinner : sushi },
       { id: 18, dinner : hummus }
]
```

I'm trying to remove values from array1 that are not in array2 based on the id.

I know how to remove in two single dimensional arrays but I'm unable to modify the code to remove when array2 is an array of Objects.

```
const array1 = array1.filter(id => array2.includes(id));
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "multidimensional"? Both arrays have single dimension in above example

Comment: array1.filter( i => (array2.map(o => o.id)).includes(i))

Comment: `reduce` would perform better to avoid two passes. Elaborating below:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `map` all Ids and then `filter`

```js
var array1 = [1, 3, 15, 16, 18];

var array2 = [
       { id: 1, dinner : "pizza" },
       { id: 15, dinner : "sushi" },
       { id: 18, dinner : "hummus" }
]

  const Ids = array2.map(i=> i.id);
  var res = array2.filter(i => Ids.includes(i.id)); 
  var res2 = Ids.filter(i => array1.includes(i))// Or, just to get common Ids
  
  console.log(res)
   console.log(res2)
```

But I suggest you should use `reduce` to avoid **two passes**:

```js
var array1 = [1, 3, 15, 16, 18];

var array2 = [
       { id: 1, dinner : "pizza" },
       { id: 15, dinner : "sushi" },
       { id: 18, dinner : "hummus" }
]

var res = array2.reduce((acc, {id})=>{
  if(array1.includes(id)){
   acc = [...acc, id]
  }
  return acc
},[]);

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

Both arrays are single dimension arrays.

use `.some()` function along with `.filter()` function to remove those numbers from `array1` which are not present as id in any of the objects in `array2`

```js
const array1 = [1, 3, 15, 16, 18];
const array2 = [
    { id: 1, dinner : 'pizza' },
    { id: 15, dinner : 'sushi' },
    { id: 18, dinner : 'hummus' }
]

const filteredArr = array1.filter(v => array2.some(o => v == o.id));

console.log(filteredArr);
```